# jQuery load page with auto height on content

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am using this jQuery to load my content into a div. How can i replace to 1000px height in the object into auto? So when it loads, it re-sizes into the correct size?

```
 <div id="siteloader" style="width: 100%; height:auto;"></div>​
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $("#siteloader").html('<object data="content.html" style="width: 100%; height:1000px;">');
</script>
```

Comment: Can you set up a jsfiddle?

Comment: That would help. If you don't know how, just go to http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
   $(window).load(function() {
       $("#siteloader").html('<object data="content.html" style="width: 100%; height:1000px;">');

   });
 </script>
```